# Pretty-Print parameters for Spring + REST

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, model-view-controller

I write code with this tutorial(https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) and now I have this output:

```java
[{"id":1,"name":"Bilbo Baggins","role":"burglar"},{"id":2,"name":"Frodo Baggins","role":"thief"}]
```

But in tutorial it turned out differently:

```java
{
  "_embedded": {
    "employeeList": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bilbo Baggins",
        "role": "burglar",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees/1"
          },
          "employees": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Frodo Baggins",
        "role": "thief",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees/2"
          },
          "employees": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees"
    }
  }
}
```

I know, it's because JSON, but how I can change this?

Version: Java jdk 12, Intelij Idea last upd, Spring MVC 5.2.4;

My code: https://github.com/Rogue06/demonica

Comment: Where in that repo are you creating a json file?

Comment: I do not have such a file. I am studying Spring and REST recently, so I would like to get a step-by-step guide on changing the look of this rest message.

Comment: Where, in that repo, are you sending back, or receiving, that JSON output. How are you displaying it?

Comment: How do you call the endpoint `/employees`? With your browser? Try to delete the browser cache or call the `http://localhost:8081/employees` from an incognitio window. My output looks exactly like what you desire when I clone your repo

Comment: it is also worth noting that in the tutorial they do go on to show an example output that is exactly what you're getting because of the CollectionModel and EntityModel classes.

Comment: Sorry, guys. I forgor add my port 8081. thanks

Comment: "Last version" is not helpful to future readers and is a hassle for current ones; provide the actual version. This is a Jackson configuration option. Are you using Boot? If so, the property you're looking for is `spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following code to app.properties:

```java
spring.jackson.serialization.INDENT_OUTPUT=true
```